# Turning search constraint results into database data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Currently i have a search form where i can query my database for 'Batsmen" on their name and their nationality. This works fine in terms of showing batsmen matching the constraints but im trying to create is some text that tells the user what they searched. currently i can return the id values of the nationality_ID but i want to return the name field of that nationality_id, here is what i have so far :

Tables: **Batsmen:**: ID, Name, Nationality_ID; 
**Nationality**: ID, name, 
**Comment**: ID, comment, batsmen_id

Search Form:

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'search.index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">

                    {!! Form::label('batsmenname', 'Search By Name:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('batsmenname', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('nationality_id', 'Search By Nation:') !!}
                <select class="form-control" name="nationality_id" >
                    <option value=""></option>

                    @foreach($nationality as $nation)

                        <option value="{{$nation->id}}">{{$nation->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
           {!! Form::submit('Find Batsmen', array('class' => 'btn-send btn-lg btn-block')) !!}

            {!! Form::close() !!}
           </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $batsmenQuery = Batsmen::where('approved', '=', 1)
        $nationality = Nationality::all()->sortBy('name') ;

        $batname=$request->input('batsmenname');
        $location=$request->input('nationality_id');

        if(!empty($batname)){
        $batsmenQuery->where('batsmenname', 'LIKE', '%'.$batname.'%')->get();
        }

        if(!empty($location)){
        $batsmenQuery->where('nationality_id', $request->input('categories_id') )->get();
        }
        $batsmen= $batsmenQuery->paginate(40);

        return view('page.search')->withBatsmen($batsmen)->withBatname($batname)->withLocation($location)



}
```

Batsmen Models:

```
   public function nationality(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Nationality','nationality_id');
    }
```

Results HTML :

```
<h4 class="result">{{($batsmen->total())}} batsmen found matching your search criteria: ('{{$batname}}', {{$location}})</p>
```

The Question is how do i get the id number that shows in $location to show **name** field of that Nationality_ID it is showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `Nationality` model for the `nationality_id` you search for:

```
if ($nationality = Nationality::find($request->input('nationality_id'))) {
    $nationality_name = nationality->getAttribute('name');
} else {
    abort(404, 'No matching nationality for id ' . $request->input('nationality_id') . ' found.');
}
```

Change this to the proper plural form:

```
$nationalities = Nationality::all()->sortBy('name') ;
```

And return that to the view:

```
return view('page.search',compact('batsmen', 'batname', 'nationalities', 'nationality_name'));
```

Then in your view, use:

```
{{ $nationality_name }}
```

instead of:

```
{{ $location }}
```

Like so:

```
<h4 class="result">
     {{ $batsmen->count() }} batsmen found matching your search criteria: ('{{ $batname }}', {{ $nationality_name }})
</h4>
```

I changed total() to count(), as well.

Comment: $location isnt a model though its essentially a holder for the search constraint? so its holding whatever the nationality id is. i need to turn that into the name matching that ID.

Comment: Oops, fixed. Just change Location to Nationality

Comment: `$nationality = Nationality::find($request->input('nationality_id'));` is what you're after.

Comment: What i'm after is if $Location = 1 then to match that with the nationality_ID of the same number that $location returns and show the name field of that nationality_Id instead of $location.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I've posted? You have `$location=$request->input('nationality_id');`, I simply replaced that with `$nationality = Nationality::find($request->input('nationality_id'));`. That will find your `Nationality` with an `id` of `$request->input('nationality_id')`. You aren't even using `$location` besides what you're trying replace in the view, so it isn't needed at all.

Comment: I need the $nationality = Nationality::all()->sortBy('name') ; though for the foreach?

Comment: I've updated the answer to account for that and return the desired nationality name also.

Comment: that now returns Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null

Comment: That would mean you do not have a database record for a `Nationality` with the `nationality_id` you passed in. Are you certain it exists?

Comment: It does as it is being passed in by the search constraint which is loaded from the ->all()

Comment: That isn't lining up, you loop the nationalities, use `$nation->id` for the values in the select which is named `nationality_id`, then it can't find a record by that id? Have you changed the primary key or something in the Nationality mdoel?

Comment: Ye it was throwing a fatal error because i was searching for Localhost/search where their has yet to be a search made, so the code does work. How would i protect against it breaking when $nationality_name is null?

Comment: I added a safety check in there to handle the case of null. You can replace the `abort(404, ....)` with any logic you like.